# Decrypting a file with a different extension, but is a .png or other image file

Tags: encryption, png

I'm trying to decrypt an image that I know is an image, but it's saved in an audio/another file extension to hide what it is.

I know the file has a hex code that is a png, but I'm not sure how to open or decrypt the said file to treat it as an image file and not an unknown one.

How would I go about it?

Comment: The filename (and even the content) are irrelevant for encryption. Encryption just turns one byte sequence into another byte sequence, no matter what the bytes are.

Comment: I was also looking at the hex codes and noticed most of the images started with BA or BF.

Comment: ".. saved in an audio/another file extension to hide what it is." So they fooled you by changing the file extension. Why not just change it back to .PNG?